# FQL Query All User Comments, and Likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

referencing

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

I don't see any obvious way of getting all comments by a user, or all likes.

If tried such queries as https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT post_fbid, fromid, text, time FROM comment WHERE fromid={1}&access_token={0}

and variations with me(), and such, but the clearly won't work per the documentation stating the WHERE clause must be associate with a * column defined in the documentation.

Does anyone know a way of getting all comments by a user, or all likes by a user?

to be more specific... Likes by user all together... not just "like" a page.

Answer (score 1):

I used a FQL something like this for get all likes from current logged in user.

```
SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API for that. A [User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) has connections to `Posts`, `Likes` and `Feed` (you'll need various permissions for each, see the API docs). By accessing this link with a valid access token you can see your likes: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes

And here it is in the Graph API Explorer: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Flikes

Comment: Yes, I found this info. I'm talking about everything a user has pressed "like" on in facebook. This method call the pages the user has liked, not, for instance, the specific status updates or comments a user has liked.